# Easy Deployment Split Tunnel VPN Connection

Tags: windows, vpn, deployment, mac, rras

I was wondering if anybody could offer some insight as to how I can mass deploy VPN connection settings that support split tunneling. It has to work on both Mac and Windows systems though if a script is used, it obviously can be 2 separate scripts for both platforms.

I will be setting up a Windows server with a file server and Exchange server and to access the file server I will have the clients go through VPN because we will have sensitive data. I don't want the servers network to be bogged down with the clients normal internet traffic so I will be needing some way to setup split tunneling on the clients without them having to put in a few commands every time to setup the static routes.

Ive looked at Cisco VPN client but I want to try and stick with windows RRAS and avoid buying a Cisco VPN endpoint. Im basically looking for a good VPN client that can support split tunneling and mass deployment.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using RRAS, then use the built-in Windows VPN client.